# Add show more for scrollview in appceleraotor

Tags: scrollview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, scrollable

I want to display 250-300 images for scrollview,initially only 10 images i will display after click on show more i need to display again 10 images with scrollview.
 i have tried with Scrollable view but it is scroll horizontally?but i need to display images vertically.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options to do a vertical scroll view:

- [Ti.UI.ScrollView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView)
- [Ti.UI.ListView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView)
- [Ti.UI.TableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView)

The second one is the most performant and there are [several widgets](http://gitt.io/search?q=infinite) to help you with adding more images as the user scrolls down.